# Responsive Background Image Resize Issue

Tags: html, image, background, responsive-design

I need some help resolving an issue with a background image. When I reduce the screen resolution from 960 to 768, the YouTube logo in the "More Videos" sidebar on the index page does not scale. It also gets cut off as the viewport becomes smaller.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Here is a link to github --> [link](http://blacktiph.github.com/project1/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link doesn't work, so I'm just going to guess here that the background image is a property of a div.

The div is probably getting scaled, but not so the image in the background. And that's the intended behaviour.

You can, however, make the background image also responsive. Check this link for more information:
http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios